PC 'randomly' restarting w/o blue screens after installing Windows 11 - what to do?
I flashed my Gigabyte Z390 D motherboard to a newer BIOS and found out I can actually run windows 11 with my setup. I then made a fresh install of windows 11 and set up my pc regularly.
I am getting 'random' restarts every 5 minutes or less and I am getting frustrated. I am getting Kernel-Power events (id 41) in my event viewer whenever this happens.
My setup:

Gigabyte Z390 D
i7-9700K (no OC)
32 GB GSkill ripjaws 3200MT/s
ASUS GeForce GTX 1070ti (no OC) 512GB kingston nvme ssd

Components were bought new and appear to be physically fine. There are no high temperatures during load and the crashes don't seem to correlate to load.
I have eased the crashing by disabling XMP and setting balanced power instead of high performance. I didn't have these issues on Win10 just a day before. I've also tried a few bios tweaks, including turning of CSM, cpu virtualization settings, utilizing default BIOS settings after flash etc.
I executed disk checks and memory checks, hasn't fixed anything. Not sure what to do or how to diagnose this. Currently I'm tinkering with making a stable memory profile myself. I have a hunch that the increased memory voltage is causing issues. I've raised the stock 2133MT/s to 2600MT/s without raising voltage and haven't had a crash for ~20 minutes even with performance power plan.
Update:
PC runs stable with BIOS tweaks. Namely, RAM works fine @3200MT/s BUT with 1.18v or 1.2v, not with the XMP's 1.35v. I still don't understand why 1.35v causes issues on win11 though.

Whats your PSU wattage(should be at least 550W)? Also, did you check PSU power output in bios(usually around "hardware monitor" or similar words) and check stability of voltage? Deviations of 3-5% are OK(ie. 12v rail can deviate between 11.4v-12.6v).

PSU has 700W. Deviations have been very interesting!
Core VID:

minimum: 1.118V
maximum: 1.279V

Not sure where to find other voltage values in hwinfo

Nevermind last comment. +12V sensors show minimum of 12.168V and maximum of 12.168V (no difference). Interestingly DDR voltage shows minimum of 1.368V and maximum of 1.380V even though I set BIOS to 1.2V.

Soz, not mentioned to check only 3.3v, 5v, and 12v rails...core will always jump around, I'm rly unsure about ram,...should be static at set voltage(or on default if something is faulty or simply mismatched), and not sure that it should change at all.

Thanks for the input. Had 0 crashes with custom memory profile even though RAM states 1.35v (same as xmp profile). Hope something random fixed it and I'm never changing anything again \o/

Np, you can push test on ram if you want with (https://www.memtest86.com/downloads/memtest86-usb.zip) ,if it says its ok, then something is on mobo side. As you mentioned, some setting doesn't apply properly, try re-flash bios with bios redownload too maybe? Rarely downloads could go bad without any error(CRC) popping out, rare, but can happen.
